# Debug PHP with Xdebug in Docker with VSCode on Mac

Tags: php, docker, xdebug

I am running a Symfony application inside a Docker-Container.
I want to debug the code with VSCode on my mac. With Windows everything works fine.
The debugger is connecting to the container, but does not stop at the breakpoints.

This is my **launch.json**

```
{
"version": "0.1.0",
"configurations": [{
        "name": "Listen for XDebug",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "port": 9003,
        "log": true,
        "externalConsole": false,
        "pathMappings": {
            "/srv/app": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "/srv/cssp/src/WorkingBundle": "${workspaceFolder}/src/WorkingBundle"
        },
        "ignore": [
            "**/vendor/**/*.php"
        ]
    },
]
```

In the **php.ini** I added

```
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal
xdebug.start_with_request=trigger
```

My **Dockerfile**

```
FROM composer:latest AS composer
FROM php:7.2-apache-stretch


COPY --chown=33:33 . /srv/cssp
COPY .docker/vhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
COPY .docker/php.ini /usr/local/lib/
COPY .docker/php.ini /usr/local/lib/php
COPY .docker/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php

WORKDIR /srv/symfonyApp

ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER 1

COPY --from=composer /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /srv/symfonyApp\
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y install libpng-dev libjpeg-dev unzip\
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) mbstring mysqli pdo pdo_mysql shmop zip gd \
    && a2enmod rewrite ssl socache_shmcb \
    && service apache2 restart \
    && composer install \
    && chown -R www-data:www-data /srv/symfonyApp\
    && useradd -rm -d /home/symfonyApp -s /bin/bash -g root -G sudo -u 503 cssp \
    && pecl install xdebug \
    && apt install nano \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug \
    && apt-get install libfontconfig1 libxrender1 libxtst6
```

And my **docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.8'
services:
app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: .docker/Dockerfile
      image: symfonyApp-docker
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    links:
      - mysql
    volumes:
      - .:/srv/symfonyApp
    environment:
      PHP_IDE_CONFIG: 'serverName=localhost'
      XDEBUG_SESSION: 'VSCODE'
  mysql:
    image: mariadb:10.4.4
    container_name: symfonyApp_mysql
    volumes:
      - .docker/mysql/init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

    restart: always
    ports:
      - 13306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
```

Comment: So just to clarify: debugging works OK on Windows (breakpoints get hit etc) but the same image cannot be debugged on Mac (Xdebug connects to the client (VSCode) but breakpoint is not getting triggered), right? 1) Can you enable Xdebug log (`xdebug.log`) and try to debug the same URL (simple script) so we can compare the responses 2) In docker -related files I see `/srv/symfonyApp` while in VSCode config I see `/srv/app` -- is that just a typo (when obfuscating the app name) or is it actually a wrong path? Double check it just in case.